# Load React in an overlay on a non React website

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm wondering what the best way is to load React in an overlay on a Wordpress site that uses JQuery. I don't want to load React (and Babel) before the user clicks the button that opens the overlay, so I'll have to manage that part with JQuery.

But I'm not sure about the best way to write the script tag that loads React so I'll know when it's ready to execute

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You say " I don't want to load React (and Babel) before the user clicks the button that opens the overlay,", but why is that really? What are you trying to avoid here? Off hand, I'd say the simplest way would be to use an iframe in the overlay and set the `src` attribute to point to your separate file when the user clicks to open the overlay. That said, i'd just load it on every page load and let it ride if it were me.

Comment: Fair point. The reason is that because of Wordpress, and all its crud, it's already pretty heavy + this feature is only needed on just a few pages. I don't want to add to the crud

Comment: Keep in mind that the user's browser is gonna cache the files on the first visit then just serve the cached versions after that. Honestly, I wouldnt worry about the extra files / load unless you have real reason to believe they are a burden. Another point worth mentioning is that when testing, if you have cache disabled (I always do), page loads can seem longer than they really are for actual users.